# issue with subdivision surface modifier in cube

Tags: modeling, vertices, subdivision-surface

I have noticed that the subdivision surface modifier does not work when it's not applied.I would appreceate any given answer.[[image: I have noticed that the subdivision surface modifier does not work when it's not applied.I would appreceate any given answer.! 1]

Comment: You need to apply if you want to move the vertices that the modifier creates, otherwise you can't

Comment: As moonboots said, you will have to apply it. In your modifier, beside the cross mark, there's a downwards arrow to open a dropdown menu. Click it and select apply.

Comment: You can also hover over the modifier on the settings panel and hit Ctrl-A to apply it.

Comment: That's the way modifiers work - they are supposed not to alter the mesh unless applied, this way you are able to easily make changes to the settings without having to revert an otherwise "destroyed" mesh. And just for completeness, another way to apply modifiers (all modifiers at once to be precise, if you have multiple on the object) would be to press Ctrl+A in the viewport and choose _Visual Geometry to Mesh_.